# Java do while not looping

Tags: java

I'm sure this is going to be something dumb, but I cannot get my do while loop to work can someone take look please? I need the user to enter a number, then this is validated in a while loop. Then this number gets added to an arraylist and keeps looping until the user enters "-1". Here is my code:

```
public void enterValues(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values) {

  do {
    System.out.print("Enter value to convert: £");
    while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a double");
      scan.nextLine();
    }

    values.add(scan.nextDouble());
    System.out.print("Value entered. Enter -1 to stop: ");
  }

  while (!scan.next().equals("-1"));

  System.out.println("Values entered. Returning to main menu.");
  mainMenu(scan, values);
```

Comment: I'm thinking `scan.next()` will get any value, not just integers.  Let me check it out though.

Comment: scan.next() reads the next token, that is a String indeed.

Comment: What are you console input and output ?

Comment: and exactly where is it failing?

Comment: Note that `nextDouble` doesn't consume the `\n`. It'll be consumed in the `nextLine`.

Comment: You what the user to enter the number and that should be converted to double? Is that you want?@james

Comment: When the double is entered, the program notifies the user that the value has been entered. It is here the user needs to enter something else before the loop can continue. I want to remove this and have the loop run automatically without the users input. Eran explained it better in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
public void enterValues(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values){
    Double dValue= (double) 0;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter value to convert: £");
        dValue= scan.nextDouble();
        if(dValue != -1)
            values.add(dValue);
    }while(dValue != -1);

    System.out.println("Values entered. Returning to main menu.");
    mainMenu(scan, values);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you. And i hope you wanted to do this.@James B

Comment: Thanks for this, I am unable to get the loop to end however. Entering -1 is the same as entering a double and does not end the loop.

Comment: I ran the above code and checked in my system and posted.It works for me.@James

Comment: My mistake, I missed out something. It works now. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the other answer below, but a little more idiomatic.  There's no need to check the input value twice.  Just check it once, and use `break` to exit the loop if it's negative.

```
   public void enterValues(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values) {

        for( ;; ) {
            System.out.print("Enter value to convert: £");
            while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a double");
                scan.nextLine();
            }
            double input = scan.nextDouble();
            if( input < 0 ) break;
            values.add( input );
            System.out.println("Value entered. Enter -1 to stop: "+ values );
        }
   }
```

If you actually need "-1" and not just any negative number, note that it's poor practice to compare doubles with `==`.  Use a tolerances with the difference.  Also notice below that I supply my input with the program to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

```
public class ScannerTest
{
   private static final String[] testVectors = {
      "123\n456\n890\n-1\n",
   };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < testVectors.length; i++) {
         String testInput = testVectors[i];
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(testInput);
         ArrayList<Double> output = new ArrayList<>();
         new ScannerTest().enterValues( scan, output );
         System.out.println( output );
      }
   }

   public void enterValues(Scanner scan, ArrayList<Double> values) {

        for( ;; ) {
            System.out.print("Enter value to convert: £");
            while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a double");
                scan.nextLine();
            }
            double input = scan.nextDouble();
            if( compareDouble( input, -1.0, 0.00001 ) ) break;
            values.add( input );
            System.out.println("Value entered. Enter -1 to stop: "+ values );
        }
   }

   private boolean compareDouble( double d1, double d2, double tolerance ) {
      return Math.abs( d1 - d2 ) < tolerance;
   }

}
```